# Pipe is fine, solenoid is fine, but can't get hot water into my washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine

So let my start off by saying, the installation techs installed the valves backwards at first, so I was getting hot water out of my cold, never noticed that until my room mate was pissed at me for washing on hot because it was going to make our electricity go up... So I switched the hoses blue to blue, red to red, now only cold water comes out!! Figured it was the hot water valve/solenoid, so I got a new one. Nope. Same problem. If I set to hot water and turn off the cold water I get a humming noise and no water comes out, or if I keep the cold water valve on, only cold water is coming out. What is the issue?! Is it the technicians fault? Did they screw sensors up by installing backwards? I have a Samsung model WA40J3000AW/A2. Brand new, no clogs or anything that I can gather. valves are clean. water comes out of both pipes when disconnected from the washer at the correct temperature.

Comment: Have you checked the hose/valve filter for blockage? occasionally I've found rust, etc., blocking the water. Have you checked that there is hot water to the hose, and there is no shut-off upstream & back to the water heater?

Comment: Sounds like a warranty issue to me if the valve is buzzing the line after it may be blocked, since you had hot water running through the cold valve the supply line is good.

Answer (score 1):

If it is delivering cold when you call for **hot only** then it is opening the wrong valve (assuming your statement that the hoses are correct now is true).

Return the unit, it is malfunctioning and it seems like a **controller** issue not a valve or solenoid issue.

*However*; you state that you replaced a "valve/solenoid". Are you certain you did it right? Are you certain you wired it right? If the unit was "brand new" why did you do that yourself instead of having a factory approved technician troubleshoot and repair the unit under warranty?